# SQL - select with multiple references and clause IN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, multiple-tables

could help me?

I have in my database for a salon table having N records in the Employees table.

```
SELECT s.nome_salao, f.nome_funcionario 
FROM funcionario f NATURAL JOIN salao s 
WHERE s.email_salao IN (SELECT email_salao FROM salao 
           WHERE codigo_estado = 2 AND cidade_salao = 'São Paulo' 
           AND bairro_salao = 'Limoeiros') 
ORDER BY f.nome_funcionario;
```

I have a query where I want to select the salon name (nome_salao) to which the employee belongs. But I want to do this research for all salons that are in a given location.

The subquery returns two salons, and each salon have several employees.

So I want to return only the salon name to which each employee belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL fails? returns nothing? returns something unexpected?

I dont know if I understood your problem, but i think that this should do the trick without IN and subqueries.

```
SELECT 
    s.nome_salao, 
    f.nome_funcionario 
FROM funcionario f 
    NATURAL JOIN salao s 
WHERE s.codigo_estado = 2
AND s.bairro_salao = 'Limoeiros'
ORDER BY f.nome_funcionario;
```